# How to save Excel date time cell into MySQL using VBA?

Tags: excel, mysql, ado, vba

The mysql table has a DATETIME field. I want to INSERT a new row into this field using the cell data from the Excel worksheet. But I cannot use the datetime formatted cell value in a INSERT INTO query. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Clarifying how you are using VBA would be helpful, but assuming that you are using VBA primarily to bring the data up to MySQL, you can handle a lot of your formatting right in your Excel workbook.  For DATE type data,

```
=TEXT([the data],"YYYYMMDD")
```

is effective.

For DATETIME type data,

```
=TEXT([the data],"YYYYMMDDHHMMSS")
```

gets interpreted correctly at import by MySQL.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have to say, this may be one of the most helpful bits of code I've seen to help with importing to MySQL with excel; thank you very much.  For the longest time, I have had trouble with excel auto formatting my date strings to unusable values.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom format that represents the datetime in the correct way.